# will updating cygwin setup file delete my entire cygwin installation

Tags: cygwin, updates

I had downloaded cygwin from one mirror site, and after a few months when I try to update now I get the message that the "current ini file is from a newer version of setup-x86_64.exe"

If I download a new ini file, does it also mean that the entire cygwin installation will have to be downloaded again? That will take a huge time and I would like to avoid it.

Also, what is a stable mirror site for cygwin? On some update occassions, I have got the message that the site is no more a "recommended" site, and I should select another mirror site.

Comment: I got it even when using the latest. I found if choosing the gtlib.gatech server it was fine.. I chose a server that sounded academic, and it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your main question is **NO**. That message appears because the `setup-x86_64.exe` file has been updated.  You need to download a recent version at http://www.cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe.

Mirror sites are updated on a schedule, so the updates at mirrors are always behind the main Cygwin site by a certain amount. Some sites update more frequently than others.  From the [Cygwin mirror admin site](https://cygwin.com/mirrors.html#mirroradmin):

> Given the granularity of checking, it is possible that your site will
>   be  polled after a package update on cygwin.com but before your site
>   has  pulled the update. So, it is expected that from, time-to-time,
>   your site  may fall off the mirror list temporarily. If your mirror
>   site has not  been listed for a day or so that means that some cygwin
>   packages on your  site are not current. Check the cygwin-announce
>   archives for  announcements about recent package updates and ensure
>   that your site has  those packages. Once your site has the recent
>   packages it will be  re-added automatically.

and

> So, if your site was dropped from the list it means that a program has
>   determined that the files on your site are not up-to-date. Unless your
>   site has been out of date for (currently) 100 runs of the program, it 
>   will be re-added automatically when it becomes current. So, if you see
>   that your site has been dropped from the mirrors list do not panic.

I’ve generally found that unless you repeatedly get the message about it not being a recommended site, there's nothing to worry about, just try again in a few hours or the next day.  Picking the site closest to you is generally a good bet.

Comment: thanks very much for the detailed reply. Saves me a lot of worry :)

Answer (score 3):

You just need to download a newer version of the `setup.exe` file and perform the update with that.

During the setup you'll be presented with a list of recommended mirror sites, choose one near to you and you're good to go.

No worries. :-)